# what does double square brackets mean in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, syntax

the below is the sample code in swift.

```
var loadedMessages = [[Message]]()
```

Message is a custom class. i'm not sure what [[Message]] () is doing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is specifying that your variable `loadedMessages` is an array of arrays that contains `Message` objects. A JSON representation of `loadedMessages` might look like:

```
loadedMessages: [
  [ <Message>, <Message>, <Message> ],
  [ <Message>, <Message>, <Message> ]
]
```

A quick Playground implementation of something similar can give you a pretty good introspection of the situation:

```
var foo = [[String]]()
foo.append(["bar"])
foo[0][0] // reveals "bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

It means it’s an array of arrays of messages.  Think of it in terms of whatever appears between the square brackets being an array of that, and this can include another array.

Alternatively, if you were to write out without the “shorthand” array syntax, it would be `Array<Array<Messages>>()`.